# OptaPlanner: SolverManager::solveAndListen synchronization/locking bug?

Tags: java, asynchronous, optaplanner

OptaPlanner v8.22.1.Final

`TL;DR`: the default `SolverListener` implementation, `DefaultSolverListener`, doesn't sync. properly for the `Consumer<? super Solution_> finalBestSolutionConsumer`... or I'm misunderstanding the purpose of this `Consumer`.

Is this the intended behavior?

The details:

I've found recently some of my tests logging warnings about the last-current-best solution not matching the final-best solution.

The cause is `terminateEarly` not waiting for the final-best solution `Consumer` thread to finish.

This isn't a huge problem, because the last-current-best solution is available through the intermediate solutions, but it doesn't seem right that final-best isn't being saved.

I have the following call that starts the optimization:

```java
this.getSolverManager()
    .solveAndListen(solutionID,
                    this::findCurrentBest,
                    this::saveCurrentBest,
                    this::saveFinalBest,
                    this::handleException);
```

`saveFinalBest` is this, so it's not like it's an expensive call:

```java
this.finalBestConsumer.accept(finalBest); // does nothing by default
this.finalBestSolutionsMap.put(finalBest.getId(), finalBest);
```

And we complain:

```java
// logging
this.getSolverManager().terminateEarly(solutionID);
// logging

final var finalBest = this.findFinalBest(solutionID);
final var crrntBest = this.findCurrentBest(solutionID);
final var best = ObjectUtils.max(finalBest, crrntBest);

if (!Objects.equals(finalBest, crrntBest)) {
    // complain
}

return best;
```

What I'm finding is that `terminateEarly` returns and we do `findFinalBest` before the final-best is saved.

So, am I misunderstanding?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SolverManager.terminateEarly()` does not provide any guarantees regarding when the consumption of the final best solution happens.

When the `Solver` terminates, either by the configured termination or early, the last known best solution is passed to the final best solution consumer.

The consumer (both the intermediate and the final one) runs in a dedicated thread and there is truly no synchronization between this thread and the `SolverManager.terminateEarly()`.

Consuming the best solution can be a long-running operation, outside of the control of the `Solver`. If `terminateEarly()` waited for the consumption to finish, it may lead, for instance, to HTTP request timeouts in the caller thread.

If you want to wait for the final best solution, you can synchronize inside the final best solution consumer, which works for both the normal and early termination.

The Javadoc should explain this clearly, though.

Comment: Thank you.  Yeah, that could definitely be clearer in the JavaDoc.